# Como insertar dato fecha de la pc a sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

Tengo un TextBox que me captura la fecha de la maquina mediante este codigo:

> TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

tengo un campo en mi tabla de sql llamado Fecha de tipo date

Cuando trato de insertar el dato

> insert into tblprueba (fecha) values('" & TextBox1.Text &"')",con)

me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de tipo de dato, recibes la fecha como texto y necesitas convertirlo al tipo Date para insertarla en tu base de datos.

```
Dim MiFecha as date
MiFecha = Date.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
```

Luego usas la variable en tu insert

```
insert into tblprueba (fecha) values('" & MiFecha &"')",con)
```

Quiza tengas que cambiar el formato, no lo puedo probar ahora mismo, pero debería funcionar ;)